# TraceListener to trace WCF events, but not self generated events

Tags: .net, wcf, tracelistener, tracesource

Our shop has a TraceListener that send events to a repository via a webservice call.  We use it for our own TraceSources, but want to be able to use it for other TraceSources, like System.ServiceModel and System.Activities.

```
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"      propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
    <add name="TheSharedListenerInQuestion" />
    </listeners>
    </source>
```

The problem is we use a WCF client call to do the Write within the TraceListener and if the System.ServiceModel tracesource is attached to my listener I end up in a loop, eg trace an event which fires the internal client call, which in turn makes the WCF tracesource fire a TraceEvent and the loop ensues.

How do I make my internal WCF call not cause the WCF tracesources to fire?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is logically possible. To use code-under-trace in the trace listener will necessarily create an infinite loop, however, that said:

One crazy idea would be to write a custom [TraceFilter](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/04/custom-trace-filter-for-a-wcf-service/) that inspects the stack trace to see if the tracelistener is the origin of the call or if it is some other client.  There may be another more clever solution, I would have to set a break point inside a custom trace Filter and look to see if anything about the context is distinguishable (maybe by filtering on the endpoint name)